# Filter datasource using a collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I want to show this data source (on the left) in my power app filtered by Jobs. Those jobs lay in a collection.

How does one filter a table using a collection ? Can I use forAll ?

[image: ForAll]

Comment: This formula does not show any syntaxe misstake but the algorythm is incorrect:                                            Filter(Table2;Job=ForAll(Gallery1.AllItems; ThisRecord.Job))

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the following :

Filter(Table2__2; Job in BestScores.Job);